# Does using a Lookup column require a manual selection to initiate?

Tags: sharepoint-online, lookup-column, sharepoint-list

My users manually enter an alphanumeric value for each record in List A. I want that value to match up with the same value in List B so that another column in List B shows up in List A.

At first, I was thinking of using a Lookup column for this but if I'm not mistaken, this would require a user to choose a "connecting" value from a list first.

Selecting a value from an ever-growing list of values is not practical (right now I have 1,000), which is why I'm looking for a method that will do this match automatically.

So, can this be done without selecting a value from a Lookup column to initiate this connection?

Answer (score 0):

We can "join" two lists using SharePoint designer. Please have a look here:
http://www.macaalay.com/2013/12/17/join-two-sharepoint-lists-together-by-id/

Comment: Thank you, sourav!

Answer (score 0):

[Lookup columns](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-list-relationships-by-using-unique-and-lookup-columns-80a3e0a6-8016-41fb-ad09-8bf16d490632) do require manual selection to fill in the values and build a connection between lists.

You can also automatic this process using **SharePoint Designer 2013 workflow**.

Here is an example:

[image]

Please note that we cannot update the lookup column using a normal column since it will cause format conflict error. The column I use in the test is the *ID* column of the source list.

Comment: Understood, Chelsea. Thank you!

Comment: Chelsea: is there a way to have the looked-up value show on the form itself? Or can it only be seen in a list view?

Comment: @rizingfenix Yes. If you are using the default list form, the new created column (including lookup column) will be automatically displayed on the list form. But if you are using customized form, the list field will need to be manually added to the form.

Comment: I have the menu added to the form, but the value I'm interested in carrying over from the other list isn't a field choice at all in InfoPath.  ???

Comment: In other words, if I'm looking at just the *list* view, I can see both the values: the one in the dropdown menu and the value that I'm really interested in carrying over. But I can't find a way to make that show in the form via InfoPath.

Comment: @rizingfenix Ok, got what you mean. The additional column for the lookup column is not an option. It will only show in list view and the Display form of the item, not the New/Edit form because it does not allow manual filling in, so it will not show when you build the InfoPath form either.

Comment: Got it. Thanks, again!